# Trying to model a simple second order ODE

Tags: matlab, ode

I am studying some computational methods and I am trying to program simples equations to understand how the methods work... Particularly, I am trying to understand how multiorders ODE's work.

I've tried to program the ODE $y''=y'+x$, with conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y(h)=-h^2/2-h$, ie, the function $y=-x^2/2-x$.

So, I've used central diferences on second order and backward Euler on first order, getting

$$\dfrac{u_{i+1}-2u_i+u_{i-1}}{h^2}=\dfrac{u_i-u_{i-1}}{h}+x_{i+1}$$

$$u_{i+1}=u_i(h+2)+u_{i-1}(-h-1)+h^2x_{i+1}$$.

However, the result is terrible.

```
h=0.05;
max=100;
np=max/h;
u=[];
y=[];
u(1)=0;
u(2)=-h^2/2-h;
y(1)=0;
y(2)=-h^2/2-h;
x=[0:h:max];
for i=3:np+1;
    u(i)=u(i-1)*(h+2)+u(i-2)*(-h-1)+h^2*x(i);
    y(i)=-(x(i))^2/2-(x(i));
end
close all
plot(x,u)
hold on
plot(x,y,'r')
```

[image]

I know there is a lot of better methods etc, but I'd like to know why this terrible result. I mean, I didn't expect this impressive error. I am thankful in advance.

Comment: The general approach to solving second- or higher-order ODEs is to first convert them into a system of first-order equations.

Comment: [this example](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/48508) may or may not be helpful in some way

Comment: Initial conditions are not clear to me: the first one is $y(0)=0$, but it seems the other one is $y(h)=-h^2/2 - h$, instead of $y'(0)$.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thank you so much. Could you maybe cite a reference in wich there are explanations why could not I use higher orders discretizations along with others orders? Is there something wrong with scale perhaps? Many thanks!!

Comment: @VoB, thank you so much! I thinked this: $y'(0)\approx (y(h)-y(0))/h$ and so doing $y'(0)=-h/2-1\iff y(h)=-h^2/2-h$, right? Thank you!

Comment: @uhoh Thank you so much. Could you maybe cite a reference in wich there are explanations why could not I use higher orders discretizations along with others orders? Is there something wrong with scale perhaps? Many thanks!!

Comment: @VoB : The method that is implemented is a linear multi-step methods with 2 memory positions. Which means that the first step will compute $u_2$ from $u_0$ and $u_1$. $u_1$ has to be determined by some other means from $u(0)$ and $u'(0)$, the error order of $u_1$ has to be at least as high as the method order. It is not unreasonable to take the exact value there for test purposes.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, thanks. I wrote Backward Euler in my answer just because OP mentioned BE in the question, but I agree with you

Comment: @Still_waters There is nothing wrong *in principle" with using higher order discretizations. What you did wrong was to pick some discretizations apparently at random, without doing any form of error analysis on your method. That is almost never going to work. If you want to do some more "random" experiments, try using forwards, central, and backward approximations for both derivatives (which will give you 9 different methods to try).

Comment: @Still_waters Take any book on numerical methods for ODEs. The canonical reference is Hairer and Wanner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result you see is due to the long integration interval and the accumulation of truncation errors. Each step with its truncation error will switch to a slightly different exact solution. Now the exact solutions are in general
$$
y(x)=-\frac12x^2-x+C+De^x, ~~~y(0)=0\implies C+D=0.
$$
The numerical solution will move trough a sequence of exact solutions that are determined by the value pairs $u_n,u_{n+1}$.
Due to the first order approximation of the first derivative, the coefficients $C$, $D$ will grow like $h^2n=hx$. This gives a value of $5$ at $x=100$ for $h=0.05$. But the biggest contribution is due to the exponential, as $e^{100}=2.688117·10^{43}$.  This is indeed the magnitude you see in the plot.

To get a more appreciable measure, the relative error is smaller $0.1$ up to $x=4.1$, if the iteration formula is corrected to use `x(i-1)` to compute `u(i)`.

---

#### On a second look

Already setting the value $u_2$ to the exact value $y(h)$ introduces a non-zero exponential factor into the numerical solution
$$
u_n=Ax_n^2+Bx_n+C((1+h)^{n-1}-1),~~n=1,2,...
$$
as the polynomial solutions of differential and difference equation are different.
The values $A,B$ for the particular polynomial solution are determined by insertion into the difference equation,
\begin{align}
\frac{u_{i+1}-2u_i+u_{i-1}}{h^2}&=\frac{u_i-u_{i-1}}{h}+x_i\\
2A&=(A(2x_i-h)+B)+x_i\\
2A &=-Ah +B \\
0&=2A+1\\ \hline
A=-1/2,&~~B=-1-h/2
\end{align}

To get $C=0$ in the exact solution of the difference equation, the second starter value has to be chosen as $u_2=Ah^2+Bh=-h^2-h$.

With the values from the ODE solution $u_1=0$, $u_2=-h-h^2/2$ we get for the general solution
\begin{align}
u_n&=-x_n^2/2-(1+h/2)x_n+C((1+h)^{n-1}-1)
\\
-h^2/2-h=u_2&=-h^2-h+Ch
\\[.5em]
h/2&=C
\end{align}
Thus $C=h/2$ for a total error of
$$
u_{n+1}-y(x_{n+1})=h/2·((1+h)^n-1-nh).
$$
Also in this theoretical estimate the relative error is smaller than $0.1$ for $x\le 4.1$, with the absolute error smaller $0.1$ up to $x=2$.

With the corrected starter values the plot for the actual numerical computation gives a relative error of $0.1$ or smaller up to $x=34.3$. In the error plot the two phases where the error behaves like the theoretical $h/2/(1+x)$ and then switches to exponential growth are clearly recognizable.

[image: relative error, w/o modifications]

Using Kahan summation for the accumulation of the step updates for an effective computation in quadruple precision gives a relative error smaller $0.1$ up to $x=44.0$.

[image: relative error, Kahan]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is due to fact that I mix the first and second orders derivatives or just to the poor approximation? Many thanks!!

Comment: Not really. If you change it to the central difference quotient, this increases the truncation error to second order. But that only means that the coefficients $C,D$ move from zero like $h^2x$. This removes about 2 orders of magnitude from the scale, so from 41 to 39 or 38 in the power of 10. It might happen that the direction changes, so that the plot goes to the negative large numbers.

Comment: so if I understand well (once the exponential is a characteristic of the solution and could not be removed), the way to improve this is reduce to first orders ODE...? Is because of this that the way to solve ODE's is frequently reducing order? Is there something wrong with scale, perhaps? Thank you so much @Lutz Lehmann.

Comment: I make this question once in fact I need to study multiordes ODE's that I do not know the analitic solution. I do not know if there's exponential etc., so I need to minimize error without the analitic solution. Thank you!

Comment: There is no way to avoid that error. The $y$-Lipschitz constant is trivially $1$, the floating-point errors thus get magnified with factor $e^{Lx}=e^x$ and the factor to translate the local error into the global error is generally $\frac{e^{Lx}-1}{Lh}$. So independent of the method of error $p$ you will get a global error of $O(e^{x}(h^p+\mu))$. So to integrate over longer intervals than $T=35$ you need a multi-precision data type with a correspondingly smaller "machine constant" $\mu$, and need to adapt stepsize and order to fit.

Comment: In practical situations one of course avoids constructions that have exponential or faster explosions. This typically results in bounded solutions with transients towards a low-dimensional attractor manifold. In these circumstances the accumulated errors tend to have an oscillating sign and thus cancel. It sometimes seems that the largest error source is a time dilation effect, which will of course lead to large errors at larger times without changing much of the qualitative behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much @Lutz Lehmann. I got one more doubt and opened another question: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36487/2-trying-to-model-a-simple-second-order-ode-why-time-step-smaller-is-not-bett. If $hx$ is bigger, why is better $h$ bigger? Thank you so much and sorry, I am principiant.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Why is the $y$ Lipschitz constant 1? Did you reduce to first order system, so the r.h.s. is $f(y,y',x)=[y',y'+x]$ and hence the Jacobian is $J_f = $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 1  
\end{bmatrix} 
which has inf norm equal to 1?

Comment: @Vefhug : You are right, "trivially $1$" is only true if the order is reduced via $v=y'$. For the second order system one needs an adapted norm, as you computed the max norm giving the row-sum norm is suitable here. In other norms one could get other constants, but I think all give $1\le L\le 2$, so the principal argument about the error growth remains valid.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I reduced with exactly with that substitution. So,a way to check the order of a Lipschitz costant of a (smooth) vector valued functions (like this one) can be just compute the norm of the Jacobian?

Comment: @Vefhug : Yes, the Lipschitz constant is the maximum over the matrix norm of the Jacobian over a suitable set containing the expected trajectory. By carefully choosing the components of the first-order system one can sometimes balance the scales of the components so that a standard norm already gives small Lipschitz constants. For instance in the oscillator $y''+w^2y=0$ one could select $y'=wv$ so that $v'=-wy$ which gives $L\sim w$ in the standard norms.

Comment: Many thanks. Just another thing: so in this last oscillator example, since the Lipschitz constant is smaller with that substitution, then the floating point error will be magnified by a smaller factor (as $e^{Lx}$ is increasing), right @LutzLehmann ?

Comment: @Vefhug : The floating point error remains rather unchanged by such manipulations, what you get is that the theoretical prediction of it is closer to the observed error.

Comment: It's clear now, thanks for your time! Btw, do you know some online resource/book/whatever that talks about this situations? ( floating point error in ODEs, lipschitz constants, and so on ...)?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Inspired by your comments, I opened a new question on how to predict the point from where the floating point errors become visible: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36619/floating-point-and-global-error-in-euler-method

Answer (score 7):

I got your point: you have the ODE $y''=y'+x$, and we can see that $y(x)=-\frac{x^2}{2} - x$ solves the problem. As you want to integrate it numerically, you want to set *two* initial conditions, so you imposed $y(0)=0$ (and that's fine) and also another one $y(h)$, which is wrong because it's **not** the required information you need to solve an ODE, mainly because it's not **initial** condition. What you need is $y'(0)=-1$

Given that, you can recast everything into a first order system (see @WolfgangBangerth's comment)

\begin{cases}
y' = u \\
u' = u + x \\
y(0)=0 \\
u(0)=-1 
\end{cases}

Now you can choose the time integration scheme you prefer. Since you mentioned *Backward Euler*, just set the vector valued function $f(x,Y) = [u,u+x]$,
where $Y=[y,u]$ is your solution vector,
and then solve $$Y_{n+1} = Y_n + h f(x_{n+1},Y_{n+1})$$ at each time step. Notice, however, that you can avoid to use a non-linear solver, as the r.h.s. may be written as $$A Y +b$$ where

$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$
and $b= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ x \end{bmatrix}$

and hence your ODE becomes

$$Y' = A Y + b$$

and *Backward Euler* reads $$Y_{n+1} = Y_n + h(A Y_{n+1} + b(x_{n+1}))$$ i.e.

$$Y_{n+1} =(I_2 - hA)^{-1}(Y_n + h b(x_{n+1}))$$

This can be written in a simple Python snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sol(x):
    return -.5*x**2 - x

def b(x):
    return np.array([0,x])
    
A = np.array([[0,1],[0,1]])
Y0 = np.array([0.0,-1.0])
h = 0.01
T = 1.0
n = int(T/h)
x = np.linspace(0,T,n+1)
Y = np.zeros([2,n+1])
Y[:,0] = Y0.copy()
I = np.eye(2)
error = np.zeros(n)
for i in range (0,n):
    Y[:,i+1] = np.linalg.solve(I-h*A, Y[:,i]+ h*b(x[i+1]))

plt.plot(x,Y[0,:],'o',markerfacecolor='None')
plt.plot(x,sol(x),'-r')
plt.show()
```

which reproduce the solution correctly

[image]

Notice that I wrote a snippet for this *particular* case, with this *particular* r.h.s. just because it's linear! Otherwise, a Newton method would have been employed to solve the non-linear system at each time step. This latter approach can be applied wherever your r.h.s. $f$ is.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you maybe cite a reference in wich there are explanations why could not I use higher orders discretizations along with others orders? Is there something wrong with scale perhaps? Many thanks!!

Comment: Any good numerical analysis book will discuss this point: keep in mind the mantra "higher order requires higher regularity". Think about finite differences: you can obtain pretty good approximations (i.e. increasing the order) as long as your function is regular enough: that's because you are relying on Taylor expansions @Still_waters

Comment: It appears that this solver follows the polynomial path as long as the floating point errors (of size $\mu$) are not amplified into visibility, that is, until $\mu e^x\sim 1$, which gives $x\approx 37$. After that the exponential regime takes over and quickly diverges from the exact solution.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sure, that's the problem with long time integration for simple methods... but I thought the OP's question was about how to solve it. Btw, thanks for pointing that out! :-)

Comment: @VoB Thank you so much for help, and commenting with Lutz I got one more doubt and opened another question that maybe you can be interested: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36487/2-trying-to-model-a-simple-second-order-ode-why-time-step-smaller-is-not-bett. If $hx$ is bigger, why is better $h$ bigger? Thank you so much and sorry, I am principiant.

Comment: @Still_waters just an English note: I had no idea what 'principiant' meant until I googled it, I think 'I'm a novice' will better communicate what you're trying to say

Comment: @llama Thank you so much! You're right! Beginner, novice